# Случайный выбор 30% элементов списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, случайные-числа

Есть список элементов (str):

```
list_id = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13']
len_list = len(list_id)
```

При каждом запуске нужно выбрать случайный образом от 10% до 30% элементов из списка list_id.

Их нужно вывести на экран:

```
for item in list_id:
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import random

list_id = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13']

lower_bound = len(list_id) * 10 // 100
upper_bound = len(list_id) * 30 // 100

sampled = random.sample(list_id, random.randint(lower_bound, upper_bound))

for item in sampled:
    print(item)
```

Comment: "нужно выбрать от 10% до 30%".

Comment: Благодарю. Все работает, как нужно.

Answer (score 6):

В функции [random.choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) можно задать количество элементов, которые нужно случайно выбрать:

```
import random

list_id = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13']

# Случайное количество элементов от 10 до 30%
number = len(list_id) * random.randint(10, 30) // 100

print(random.choices(list_id, k=number))
```

Comment: Нужно "от 10% до 30%".

Comment: @Эникейщик, спасибо за замечание! Подправил

Comment: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'choices'

Comment: У меня python 3.4. А эта функция добавлена в 3.6. Ответ отличный, но я выберу второй. Благодарю.

Comment: @Владимир, обновляйтесь, в новых версиях появляются разные клевые ништяки :)